# App crashes after insertRowsAtIndexPaths

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to add rows dynamically to the bottom of my table view, while the user is scrolling. The idea is that the user doesn't notice this, and can scroll "endless".

When the user is reaching the bottom 40 cells of the table, I would like to draw 100 new cells to the bottom.

Now when I call

```
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: .None)
        tableView.endUpdates()
```

the application seems to crash on `tableView.endUpdates()`:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 10 beyond bounds [0 .. 9]'`

I strongly believe my dataProvider for the `UITableView` is correctly updated before I perform the updates. I don't know why it is crashing.

I made a very straight forward implementation for this purpose. Anyone understands why the below would crash?

```
private let CellTreshold: Int = 100
var cellCount: Int = 100

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

// UITableViewDataSource
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return cellCount
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCellIdentifier") as! UITableViewCell
    cell.index = indexPath.row

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if indexPath.row == cellCount - 40 {
        print("indexPath = \(indexPath.row); inserting \(CellTreshold) cells")
        var indexPaths = [NSIndexPath]()

        let beginIndex = cellCount
        let endIndex = cellCount + CellTreshold
        for i in beginIndex ..< endIndex {
            indexPaths.append(NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: 0))
        }
        cellCount += CellTreshold

        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: .None)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

Comment: Try with `let beginIndex = cellCount - 1`? Maybe you're inserting after the last one

Comment: I think it was the idea to insert the new cells after the last one. The problem is that the insertion is implemented at the method that is designed to be used for modification of the single cell it is related to, at this point it is not guaranteed that the whole table view is properly configured and prepared for new rows insertion and therefore such operation isn't safe, even if it works or used to work.

Comment: It might be worth trying to debug and find out what is `[0 .. 9]`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comments. @A-Live, yes the idea is to insert the new cells after the last one. If I understand your comment correctly the operation is not safe at this point, because it is implemented in the "willDisplayCell" method, is that correct? Do you have an alternative idea how to achieve the same result with a safe operation?

Comment: You could use scroll view delegate: load the next "page" if a) the currently displayed cells don't *initially* occupy available height or b) a threshold of ~90% scroll offset is reached. I can't say for sure that will work flawlessly - the issue might be related to the autolayout engine. Since you already have a small sample project where you can reproduce the issue, I'd recommend to create an Apple [TSI](https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/) request and attach the sample project, mention that you believe that is an Apple issue and ask for assistance at looking for a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - it was crashing, because the code was in willDisplayCell. Thanks @A-live for the comment

After I moved my code in scrollViewDidScroll its working fine, something like that:

```
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let contentHeght = scrollView.contentSize.height
    let scrollViewHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height

    if (contentHeght - offsetY) < 3*scrollViewHeight {
        //we are less than 3 page screens from the bottom

        let rowNumbers = self.dataModel.getVisibleCells()
        let newRowNumbers = self.dataModel.getMoreCells()
        let newCells = newRowNumbers - rowNumbers

        if newCells > 0 {
            debugPrint("ae.ui adding cells \(newCells)")

            let rowInd = rowNumbers - 1
            var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()
            for i in 1...newCells {
                indexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: rowInd+i, section: 0))
            }

            self.beginUpdates()
            self.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .none)
            self.endUpdates()
        }
    }
}
```